# PHP: session variable assigned within function

Tags: php, session

I have some problem understanding the behaviour of these scripts. What I want to do is to assign an array of values to a session variable from within a function like this:

```
<?php  // functions.php
function authorise() {
  $_SESSION['my_data'] = array(1 => FALSE, 2 => FALSE, 3 => FALSE, 4 => FALSE, 5 => FALSE);
  echo "<p><a href=page1.php>Click to start</a></p>";
}
?>
```

Then from my index page I will call the function

```
<?php // index.php
include_once 'header.php';
authorise();
// PRINT OUT THE CONTENT OF $_SESSION['my_data']
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  echo "no session";
} else {
  echo "session is on<br>";
  echo print_r($_SESSION['my_data']);
}
echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

After having initialised the session in `header.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php include_once 'functions.php'; ?>
```

the script will correctly print

```
Click to start

session is on
Array ( [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => ) 1
```

Yet when I reach `page1.php`

```
<?php  // page1.php
echo "PAGE1<br>";
include_once 'header.php';
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  echo "no session";
} else {
  echo "session is on<br>";
  echo print_r($_SESSION['my_data']);
}
echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

variable `$_SESSION['my_data']` is empty. The script prints

```
PAGE1
session is on
1
```

Comment: session_start() need to call on each and every script. are you doing that in page1.php?

Comment: In `page1.php` the session is on. `session_start()` is called in the included `header.php` exactly as in `index.php`.

Comment: in `page1.php`, where you are setting `$_SESSION['my_data']`, meaning where you are calling `authorise()` ???

Comment: @Makesh In `page1.php` I don't want to reset the value of  `$_SESSION['my_data']`, I want to access the value I set in `index.php`.

Comment: It supposed to work. Try accessing like : `$_SESSION['my_data'][1]` , `$_SESSION['my_data'][2]` . Are you getting proper values ? Is array converted to normal type ?